# Как перенести переменную в состояние приложения?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Есть часть кода компонента

```
const format = require('../../infra/client/utils/format')
const truncate = require('lodash.truncate')

let flag = true

module.exports = AppHeader

function AppHeader (props) {
    console.log(props)
    const { user, navigateTo, logout, assign, isSubmenuVisible, refresh, isNotRenderedYet } = props
    if (!user) {
        return
    }

    if(flag) {
        flag = false
        refresh(user)
    }
```

состояние должно управляться редукс стором, как перенести переменную flag в состояние приложения?

Comment: Я не знаю всей картины, поэтому могу сказать только что если Вы считаете что значение этой переменной место в состоянии приложения, то там её и объявляйте.

Comment: Создать редьюсер, который будет менять состояние flag, по-умолчанию задать его false. В компоненте получить этот состояние в виде пропса(props.flag)